# AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'preprocess'

Tags: keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, image-preprocessing

I already imported **preprocess** module but it continuously showed the same error. How should I solve this error?
Need help to solve this error !

**The imported Libraries are given below,**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
```

**Image Preparation,**

```
train_path = 'eggplant/training'
test_path = 'eggplant/testing'
valid_path = 'eggplant/validation'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10)
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(valid_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10)
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(test_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

**Error is given below,**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-fc384b61e2b7> in <module>()
----> 1 train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10)
      2 train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(valid_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10)
      3 train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess.input).flow_from.directory(test_path, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=10, shuffle=False)

AttributeError: module 'keras.applications.mobilenet' has no attribute 'preprocess'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `preprocess_input` instead of `preprocess.input`. As well as, you also need to change `flow_from.directory` to `flow_from_directory`.